# VSCode creates files in WSL2 as root rather than default user

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, wsl-2

I've been using WSL2 and VSCode for development for a while now with no issues. However, after a recent rebuild and reinstall of Windows I've run into an issue where when a file is created from VSCode through code, then the owner is being set as root rather than the default user. This means I'm unable to edit or save the file as I'm set as the default user and I get a permission error message from VSCode.

[Example of file permissions when created by user copying vs created from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aez7Q.png)

[Example Error Message when trying to save a file created from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMP4v.png)

The files I've been creating have been JSON files which I've created using:

```
with open("benchmark_results_words.json", "w") as bench:
        json.dump(benchmark, bench)
```

If I use chmod or chown then it sets the owner to the correct user and I've got no problems after that. I'm trying to figure out how to change the default user that VSCode uses to create files if anyone can help out.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Encountered something similar this morning and reached out to some WSL folks.

Filed an issue on VSCode here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4170